# How to check the space usage/left on the temporary table when running large queries?

Tags: postgresql, heroku-postgres

On my plan, I have a storage limit of 256GB.
After checking by https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage max size of all tables and indexes is 120GB.

```
WITH RECURSIVE pg_inherit(inhrelid, inhparent) AS
    (select inhrelid, inhparent
    FROM pg_inherits
    UNION
    SELECT child.inhrelid, parent.inhparent
    FROM pg_inherit child, pg_inherits parent
    WHERE child.inhparent = parent.inhrelid),
pg_inherit_short AS (SELECT * FROM pg_inherit WHERE inhparent NOT IN (SELECT inhrelid FROM pg_inherit))
SELECT table_schema
    , TABLE_NAME
    , row_estimate
    , pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
    SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes
    FROM (
         SELECT c.oid
              , nspname AS table_schema
              , relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , SUM(c.reltuples) OVER (partition BY parent) AS row_estimate
              , SUM(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS total_bytes
              , SUM(pg_indexes_size(c.oid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS index_bytes
              , SUM(pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS toast_bytes
              , parent
          FROM (
                SELECT pg_class.oid
                    , reltuples
                    , relname
                    , relnamespace
                    , pg_class.reltoastrelid
                    , COALESCE(inhparent, pg_class.oid) parent
                FROM pg_class
                    LEFT JOIN pg_inherit_short ON inhrelid = oid
                WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'p')
             ) c
             LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  ) a
  WHERE oid = parent
) a
ORDER BY total_bytes DESC;
```

But when I run large queries I get an answer:
"could not write to file "pg_tblspc/16400/PG_13_202007201/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp6150.1": No space left on device."

Even when running a simple query on a large table gets an error:
[image]

How I can check how much space is left in temp_table?

Or some way to check where it's stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The query is not stuck, it is writing temporary files to store intermediary results. It keeps doing that until the disk is full, then the query will fail and the files are removed.

Very likely there is an infinite recursion somewhere.

Another explanation could be that `temp_file_limit` is set too low.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Laurenz Albe
Even if I run a simple query "select from order by" for a large table it gives me back the same error. How can I check how much space there are temporary files and how much a query consumes?

Comment: You cannot predict the amount of temporary space that a query needs. To see the actual space consumption, check the remaining space in the file system.